# Dynamic regex search string from another table

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, impala

I have two tables:

**items**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  ID int,
  TXT string,
  CODE string
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES (1,'AA BB CC','ZZ-100');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (2,'BB CC DD','ZZ-200');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (3,'AA CC EE','ZZ-300');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (4,'EE FF GG','ZZ-400');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (5,'CC HH II','ZZ-500');

+----+----------+--------+
| id | txt      | code   |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | AA BB CC | ZZ-100 |
| 2  | BB CC DD | ZZ-200 |
| 3  | AA CC EE | ZZ-300 |
| 4  | EE FF GG | ZZ-400 |
| 5  | CC HH II | ZZ-500 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

And **regex_table**:

```
CREATE TABLE regex_table (
  ID int,
  REGEXSTR string,
  CODE string
);

INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(1,'AA','ZZ-100');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(1,'CC','ZZ-100');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(2,'AA','ZZ-100');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(2,'BB','ZZ-200');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(2,'CC','ZZ-200');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(3,'DD','ZZ-100');
INSERT INTO regex_table VALUES(3,'DD','ZZ-300');

+----+----------+--------+
| id | regexstr | code   |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | AA       | ZZ-100 |
| 1  | CC       | ZZ-100 |
| 2  | BB       | ZZ-200 |
| 2  | AA       | ZZ-100 |
| 2  | CC       | ZZ-200 |
| 3  | DD       | ZZ-100 |
| 3  | DD       | ZZ-300 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I would like to replace `items.txt` with search string in `regex_table.regexstr` depending on if the `id` and `code` are equal.

For example:

**Scenario 1:** If `id=1`, the `code` is `ZZ-100`, therefore the search string is `AA|CC`:

```
SELECT id,regexp_replace(txt,'AA|CC','<NA>'),code from items where id=1;

+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
| id | regexp_replace(txt, 'aa|cc', '<na>') | code   |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | <NA> BB <NA>                         | ZZ-100 |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

**Scenario 2:** If `id=2`, the `code` is `ZZ-200`, therefore the search string is `BB|CC`:

```
SELECT id,regexp_replace(txt,'BB|CC','<NA>'),code from items where id=2;

+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
| id | regexp_replace(txt, 'bb|cc', '<na>') | code   |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
| 2  | <NA> <NA> DD                         | ZZ-200 |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

**Scenario 3:** If `id=4`, the `code` is `ZZ-300`, therefore the search string is `DD`:

```
SELECT id,regexp_replace(txt,'DD','<NA>'),code from items where id=3;

+----+-----------------------------------+--------+
| id | regexp_replace(txt, 'dd', '<na>') | code   |
+----+-----------------------------------+--------+
| 3  | AA CC EE                          | ZZ-300 |
+----+-----------------------------------+--------+
```

So basically the search string has to be dynamic depending on `id` and `code` from another table.

**Is there a way to do this in one query either in Impala (important) and Hive (less important)?**

**NOTE**:

1. The `id` and `code` could be dynamic and added in both tables (so no way to hardcode into SQL). It has to be queried.
2. I try to avoid doing `JOIN`. I am wondering if there is a way to do subquery.
3. One idea is to pass a full string that contains concat Regex search string and then use some Regex tricks to remove 'id' and 'code' not relevant to the row.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this:

```
SELECT i.id, regexp_replace(txt, pattern, '<NA>'), i.code FROM items i INNER JOIN (SELECT id, group_concat('|', regexstr) AS pattern, regex_table.code FROM regex_table GROUP BY regex_table.id, regex_table.code) r ON r.id = i.id AND r.code = i.code;
```

And got this:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | regexp_replace(txt, pattern, '<na>')         | code   |
+----+----------------------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | <NA>A<NA>A<NA> <NA>B<NA>B<NA> <NA>           | ZZ-100 |
| 3  | <NA>A<NA>A<NA> <NA>C<NA>C<NA> <NA>E<NA>E<NA> | ZZ-300 |
| 2  | <NA>B<NA>B<NA> <NA> <NA>D<NA>D<NA>           | ZZ-200 |
+----+----------------------------------------------+--------+
```

**UPDATE 2**

I got it to work

```
SELECT o.id, 
       o.code, 
       items.txt, 
       o.regexstr, 
       IF(o.regexstr IS NOT NULL, regexp_replace(items.txt, o.regexstr, 
       '<NA>'), items.txt) masked 
FROM   items 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id                          id, 
                         i.code                        code, 
                         group_concat(r.regexstr, '|') regexstr 
                  FROM   items i 
                         left join (SELECT id, 
                                           regexstr, 
                                           regex_table.code 
                                    FROM   regex_table) r 
                                ON r.id = i.id 
                                   AND r.code = i.code 
                  GROUP  BY i.id, 
                            i.code) o 
              ON items.id = o.id 
                 AND items.code = o.code;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
| id | code   | txt      | regexstr | masked       |
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 5  | ZZ-500 | CC HH II | NULL     | CC HH II     |
| 2  | ZZ-200 | BB CC DD | BB|CC    | <NA> <NA> DD |
| 4  | ZZ-400 | EE FF GG | NULL     | EE FF GG     |
| 3  | ZZ-300 | AA CC EE | DD       | AA CC EE     |
| 1  | ZZ-100 | AA BB CC | CC|AA    | <NA> BB <NA> |
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

But it seems rather "complicated". Any idea to make it more concise?

Comment: I don't believe that would work as Impala or Hive doesn't support subquery inside a function expression

Comment: Yes I could do JOIN if there is a way. Less prefer though

Comment: I just posted **UPDATE 1** with the output. Syntax-wide, it works (with exception of using `group_concat` instead. But the result is strange.

Comment: Maybe replace `group_concat(..)` by `group_concat('|', collect_set(regexstr))`?

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE 2** as I got it to work. Previously if I put `group_concat` inside `regexp_replace` it would give me error. So I have to do another `SELECT` outside of it. It seems very cumbersome solution if you have any better idea.

Comment: No better idea for now. I think you should add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.id, 
       o.code, 
       items.txt, 
       o.regexstr, 
       IF(o.regexstr IS NOT NULL, regexp_replace(items.txt, o.regexstr, 
       '<NA>'), items.txt) masked 
FROM   items 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id                          id, 
                         i.code                        code, 
                         group_concat(r.regexstr, '|') regexstr 
                  FROM   items i 
                         left join (SELECT id, 
                                           regexstr, 
                                           regex_table.code 
                                    FROM   regex_table) r 
                                ON r.id = i.id 
                                   AND r.code = i.code 
                  GROUP  BY i.id, 
                            i.code) o 
              ON items.id = o.id 
                 AND items.code = o.code;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
| id | code   | txt      | regexstr | masked       |
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 5  | ZZ-500 | CC HH II | NULL     | CC HH II     |
| 2  | ZZ-200 | BB CC DD | BB|CC    | <NA> <NA> DD |
| 4  | ZZ-400 | EE FF GG | NULL     | EE FF GG     |
| 3  | ZZ-300 | AA CC EE | DD       | AA CC EE     |
| 1  | ZZ-100 | AA BB CC | CC|AA    | <NA> BB <NA> |
+----+--------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `CASE` expression to roll everything together:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN regexp_replace(txt, 'AA|CC', '<NA>')
         WHEN id = 2 THEN regexp_replace(txt, 'BB|CC', '<NA>')
         WHEN id = 3 THEN regexp_replace(txt, 'DD', '<NA>') END AS output
    code
FROM items
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry I added some clarifications above as I cannot hardcode the values